# Emacs cperl-mode make if more ergonomic

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs cperl-mode. When I type

```
if(
```

it gives me the code template:

```
if(<cursor goes here>){
}
```

But I want to make it like this:

```
if(<cursor goes here>){
    <tab, according to the mode>
}
```

So after I wrote the condition inside 'if', I won't need to click `<End>` `<Enter>` `<tab>` and will only need to click `<Down arrow>`.

The same method can be used for the similar cases: while, for, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Yasnippet](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet) to cover this case:

> YASnippet is a template system for Emacs. It allows you to type an
> abbreviation and automatically expand it into function templates.
> Bundled language templates includes: C, C++, C#, Perl, Python, Ruby,
> SQL, LaTeX, HTML, CSS and more. The snippet syntax is inspired from
> TextMate's syntax, you can even import most TextMate templates to
> YASnippet.

Your case would be just <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> *condition* <kbd>tab</kbd> *then block*.

In `cperl-mode` you have following default templates:

> eval, for, fore, if, ife, ifee, sub, unless, while, xfore, xif, xunless, xwhile

and - what's even more awesome - you can easily [create your own templates](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html) or use [an existing collection](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets) of yasnippet snippets for many languages.